# When i switch between tabs i lose variable change inside listview

Tags: android, listview, variables, tabs, android-viewpager

Like i said: for example i am in Tab1 and inside it i have a customlistview where in a row there is an EditText object.

So if i put 5, for example, it change but if i go to tab3 and then i return back to tab1 the value in EditText go back to 0.

This is my **Activity** with Tabs:

[image]

and this is the ViewPagerHolder.java

```
package com.faddex.ristorante;
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created


// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);

    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

}

//This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
        return tab1;
    }
    if(position == 1) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
    {
        Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
        return tab2;
    }
    if(position == 2)
    {
        Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
        return tab3;
    }
    if(position == 3)
    {
        Tab4 tab4 = new Tab4();
        return tab4;
    }
    if(position == 4)
    {
        Tab5 tab5 = new Tab5();
        return tab5;
    }
    else 
    {
        Tab6 tab6 = new Tab6();
        return tab6;
    } 
}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
```

}

How can i prevent reset?

Answer (score 4):

First and small approach to this is set

```
 viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

Second  approach is 
save all data of `Fragment` in

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible)
    {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);

            if (!visible)
            {
                // save all data some where
            }

    }
```

### Edit

For you , you can store data in model by `addTextChangedLinsterner` on `EditText`

Comment: What if  we have large set of date in each Page, and `setOffscreenPageLimit(5);`  Does it render all ?

Comment: @Kathi if will store data if there is large data set then second approach is preferable

Comment: @N J yes, i agree. We can do it with `savedInstanceState` ? Because while changing the device rotation, all pages in ViewPager has to recreate !

Comment: Great answer, but where i'm supposed to put viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);?

Comment: where you have added view pager for tabs

Comment: @FedericoDubbini do accept and vote up :) if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your every fragment for retaining its state `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the edittext value in some sort of model for correct state restore.

Then set this values in RecyclerView adapter for this page.